# Use of eval in a target recipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In a Makefile I'm writing I had an interest in cleaning up some of the CC prints and centralizing some of the build preparations (like creating directories in the build tree). I figured macros would be a good fit for this task. This is effectively what im trying to do, used all over various Makefiles:

```
define func
    @mkdir -p $$(dir $(1))
    @printf "%-5s $(2)\n" $(3)
endef

test:
    @echo Run
    $(eval $(call func,a,b,c))
```

My thought was that after first expansion I'd get something like (less any tabs maybe, I'm not exactly sure how the expansion works within `eval`):

```
test:
    @echo Run
    $(eval @mkdir -p $(dir a)\n@printf "%-5s b\n" c
```

and of course finally the commands would be executed. However, what I get is this:

```
# make
Makefile:7: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
```

I changed `eval` to `info` and got this:

```
        @mkdir -p $(dir a)
        @printf "%-5s b\n" c
Run
```

So I thought maybe my explicit tabs in the macro definition were causing trouble, so I removed them and tried again:

```
# make
Makefile:7: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

So it still does not quite work. If it is indeed possible at all, it seems some function of indentions in the macro, or maybe I'm defining the macros incorrectly. I thought perhaps the two commands in the macro was causing trouble (since the complaint is regarding a separator), but reducing the macro to a single line did not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `eval` here.  Eval is used to evaluate *makefile* syntax.  That is, the thing you're evaluation has to be a valid, complete makefile.  You can see that what `info` prints is not a valid makefile.  If you put that into a file and ran `make -f <file>`, you'd get a syntax error.

You are just trying to expand a variable for shell syntax.  Just remove the eval.

Comment: Funny enough, it was your comments on other similar questions that helped quite a bit regarding other Make eccentrics. A simple solution, as it tends to go. Thanks.

Comment: A good rule of thumb: if you ever find yourself trying to use make's `$(shell ...)` or `$(eval ...)` functions in a recipe, you're very likely doing something wrong.